# Binomial Probability Distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, binomial-distribution

[image]

I figured out a and b and just need help with question c, does my process below seem right? I am not sure if that is how the probability is determined

p(x)= (n/x)p^x(1-p)^n-x

(30/15)(0.5)^15(0.5)^15= 0.1445

Both groups: (0.1445)(0.1445)= 0.0209

1 group: (0.1445)(0.8555)(2)=0.247

At least 1 group buys 15 flip flops= 0.247+ 0.0209=0.268= 26.8%

Comment: Your work, shown (without explanation) at the end of your question, leads to the correct answer. My Answer is intended to provide structure, to fill in some explanations and, incidentally,  to show how to use R to do some of the computations.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(c) First, you have $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(30, .5).$
You seek the probability $p = P(X = 15) = {30 \choose 15}(1/2)^{15} = 0.1445,$ to four places. Computations in R:

```
P = dbinom(15,30,.5); P
[1] 0.1444644
choose(30,15)/2^30
[1] 0.1444644
```

[image]

Then you have a second binomial $Y$ counting groups (out of 2) who buy exactly 15 white flip flops. So
$Y \sim \mathsf{Binom}(2, p).$ And you seek 
$P(Y \ge 1) = P(Y = 1) + P(Y = 2) = 0.2681.$
You should do your own computation and compare with results below from R.

```
dbinom(1, 2, p) + dbinom(2, 2, p)
[1] 0.2680589
p^2 + 2*p*(1-p)
[1] 0.2680589
```

*Simulation in R:* In a million runs of the two-group
experiment, we find the proportion of runs on
which one or both groups bought exactly 15 white
flip flops.

The logical vector `(x1==15)|(x2==15)`, in which `|` means OR, has a million `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s;
its mean is its proportion of `TRUE`s. With a million
iterations, we can expect about two place accuracy.

```
set.seed(310)
x1 = rbinom(10^6, 30, .5)
x2 = rbinom(10^6, 30, .5)
mean((x1==15)|(x2==15))
[1] 0.268536            # aprx P(Y > 0) = 0.2680589
2*sd((x1==15)|(x2==15))/10^3
[1] 0.0008863963        # aprx 95% margin of sim err
```

*Note:* Maybe you are supposed to use a normal approximation to get $P(X = 15).$ In that case, use the mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ from (a), to standardize $X$
for the computation of $P(14.5 < X \le 15.5),$ and use printed tables of the standard normal CDF. The
normal approximation is remarkably good.

Comment: So I was right then, I did it without R and got 26.8